# Telerik grid export functionality, issue with ToGridModel()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I have included `Telerik.Web.Mvc` assembly and still not able to get `ToGridModel()` method for export function.
Below are some details about my code

```
Html.ActionLink(" ", "ExportData", new {..})

public ActionResult ExportData(...)
{

}
```

issues in code

1. Not able to define variable with IEnumerable xxx (giving error as it required  1 argument)
2. Not able to call ToGridModel() method.

Can anybody guide me how should i do this? what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've brought the extension method into scope by adding the proper `using` directive pointing to the namespace in which this extension method is defined:

```
using Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions;
```